# File read foreign characters

Tags: c#, file, encoding, char, byte

I am trying to read foreign characters from an .ini file.
This is the method I am using

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, 
                                                 int Key,
                                                 string Value,
                                                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] Result,
                                                 int Size, 
                                                 string FileName);

public static string[] GetEntryNames(string section, string iniPath)
    {
        for (int maxsize = 500; true; maxsize *= 2)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[maxsize];
            int size = Imports.GetPrivateProfileString(section, 0, "", bytes, maxsize, iniPath);
            if (size < maxsize - 2)
            {
                string entries = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0,
                                          size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
                Console.WriteLine("Entries: " + entries.Split(new char[] { '\0' })[3]);
                return entries.Split(new char[] { '\0' });
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using `Encoding.ASCII` but apparently `GetPrivateProfileString` isn't. The bytes coming out of it need encoding probably. How can I do that?

**Edit: Example**

This will print : Tavar? instead of Tavaré

Comment: Are you sure that it's not reading properly, instead of just being `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes. Set it on a label and got the same result

Comment: @JohnP. Try using `Encoding.UTF8` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` for french character

Comment: @Xiaoy312 answer the question so I can accept the answer. You deserve it

Comment: @JohnP. I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read text that contains french accents, you usually want to use one of the following encodings :

- `Encoding.UTF8`
- `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`
- `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")`

Edit: These worked for OP :

- `Encoding.UTF7`
- `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: I have virtually no C# experience*

It may be using Unicode, so try this:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
```

And this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
```

And this too:

```
Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes, 0, size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: There is no `Encoding.UTF16`, but [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) : Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I have tried all of these suggestions before posting. It's none of them.

Comment: @JohnP. `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` also didnt work?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Actually both UTF7 and will work. Thank you ;)